# Getting "sqlcmd sqlcmd: command not found" in Linux?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, sql-server-2017

Whenever I run `sqlcmd` I get "command not found"

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourPassword>'
sqlcmd: command not found
```

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First make sure [you've installed `mssql-tools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?tabs=ubuntu-install%2Credhat-offline&view=sql-server-ver16#ubuntu). Assuming you've done that, there are two methods of resolving this.

1. User-specific method [advocated in the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools): add the directory to the environmental variable `PATH`.
2. System-wide method: symlink the executable to a directory already in the path.

## User-specific Method

You can use the [tutorial's recommended method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools). The tutorial states the following:

> **Optional**: Add `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/` to your **PATH** environment variable in a bash shell.
>
> To make **sqlcmd/bcp** accessible from the bash shell for login sessions, modify your **PATH** in the **~/.bash_profile** file with the following command:
>
> ```
> echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> To make **sqlcmd/bcp** accessible from the bash shell for interactive/non-login sessions, modify the **PATH** in the **~/.bashrc** file with the following command:
>
> ```
> echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
> source ~/.bashrc
> ```

This works, but it only affects that user's sessions, and only if they use bash.

## System-wide Method

Link the MS SQL tools into a location accessible to all users:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/mssql-tools/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```

This could be in their [`postinst` script](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html), which would make sense for installing an optional package.

Both methods are compliant with the [File system Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html), which states:

> Programs to be invoked by users must be located in the directory /opt/<package>/bin

Comment: Both methods are FHS-compliant.  https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html states: "Programs to be invoked by users must be located in the directory /opt/<package>/bin".  I've submitted an edit to correct this, and make the overall flavour of the answer more neutral.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, the command is accessible only through root user, after searching lot I found following solutions. if you already installed mssql-tools directly go to next step.

follow these steps

`sudo apt-get install mssql-tools`

if mssql-tools not installed,
and if you already have it installed you will get something like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
mssql-tools is already the newest version (14.0.3.0-1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 242 not to upgrade.
```

First of all, let’s see how this tool is called on your system. It might be called something like sqlcmd-13.0.1.0 or simply sqlcmd but it should be in /opt/mssql-tools/bin/ directory. Let’s see what we have there:

```
sudo ls /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd*
```

After you get the name of the tool you can create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd /usr/bin/sqlcmd
```

That’s it.

source [mike](https://sqlserveronlinuxbackup.com/sqlcmd-command-not-found-ubuntu/)

Comment: this is basically a copy of my answer.